# How to filter JSONB list

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

I have table with this data:

```
id       | 1
accounts | [{"id": "100", "properties": [{"id": "PR-001", "name": "name1"}, {"id": "PR-002", "name": "name2"}]}]
property | "PR-001"
```

`accounts` is jsonb field.

I need to get all property.name where accounts.property.id equals property with SELECT.

I am using Postgres 9.5

Comment: this one works :) is it good?
`SELECT DISTINCT x.properties ->> 'name' FROM my_table t, (
  SELECT json_array_elements(json_array_elements(accounts :: JSON) -> 'properties') AS properties
  FROM my_table
) x WHERE x.properties ->> 'id' = t.property;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use LEFT LATERAL JOIN:

```
WITH tbl (id,accounts,property) AS (
  SELECT 1, '{"id": "100", "properties": [{"id": "PR-001", "name": "name1"}, {"id": "PR-002", "name": "name2"}]}'::jsonb, 'PR-001'::text
  )
SELECT t.id, acc->>'name'
FROM tbl t
LEFT JOIN LATERAL jsonb_array_elements(t.accounts->'properties') acc ON (acc->>'id' = t.property)
```